# facebook actionscript graph api - post to "/feed"

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, facebook-graph-api

i'm having a bit of trouble with the facebook actionscript graph api

While i can get posting to "/feed" to work with Facebook.ui, (does a facebook popup), i can't seem to get it to work with Facebook.api 
here is my code:

```
var values:Object = { 
        name:"This is my title", 
        link:"http://example.com", 
        picture:"http://example.com/icon-75x75.gif", 
        caption:"this is a caption", 
        description:"this is a long description", 
        message:"This is a test message. There are many like it but this one is mine.", 
        actions: 
        { 
                name:"Crazy extra thing", 
                link:"http://example.com" 
        } 

}; 

Facebook.api(_user + "/feed", handleSubmitFeed, values, URLRequestMethod.POST);
```

this is called after Facebook.login() with the permissions "read_stream,publish_stream,user_likes" succeeds and the id is stored in _user. I get the following error:

```
[IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: https://graph.facebook.com/********/feed"]
```

I'm not having any trouble with other calls to update the user's status ("/statuses") or retrieving their friends list.

Any ideas as to what the issue might be please?

thanks 
ob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you added the publish_stream to your permissions? I use these permissions in my own website and it works just fine:

```
public function FBConnect() 
{
    super();

    //Set applicationid
    _applicationID = "YourID";

    //Set permissions to ask for
    _extendedPermissions = {perms:"read_stream, publish_stream, user_about_me, read_friendlists, user_photos"};

    //Initialize facebook
    Facebook.init(_applicationID);
}
```

Secondly, do you have the accestoken? publishing to a stream is only allowed when you have this token. this is how I publish to a stream:

```
public function post(_message:String):void
{
    var _params:Object = new Object();

    _params.access_token = Facebook.getSession().accessToken;
    _params.message = _message;

    Facebook.api("/" + _user + "/feed", messagePosted, _params, "POST");
}
```

last of all, but i don't think this will be a problem because you can update statuses already: you know that GraphApi only works online? (or with some adjustments, it also works on localhost).

that's about it i guess, i can't think of anything else. any other questions: always welcome :)

Comment: Thankyou very much @Michiel Standaert, I added the access token which I didn't have and removed the actions object and it worked a treat. Still strange that the actions also worked when I went through Facebook.ui() though but it's a massive step in the right direction.

Comment: I know how hard graph api is, since the documentation is really louzy at the moment :) so i'm glad i could be of help ;)